# How to limit a tag to fire one time per webpage no matter the webpage opened in different browsers or devices in Matomo analytics

Tags: matomo

I’m new to matomo. I need your kind help to know how to resolve below scenario.

Let’s say there’s a webpage with a button. I want to count the button click as 1, no matter how many times user clicked the button or that webpage opened in different browsers or devices.

Please note ‘Once per pageview’ or ‘Once in lifetime’ options are not suitable for this requirement as each time a new user clicks that button, I want the clicks as 1 per user. Also if that button already counted as 1, no need to trigger that button event again for the same user.

Thanks in advance :)